# Change specific element in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm having a bit of trouble with Android's new RecyclerView. I want to create a settings activity with each option as a CardView. Inside each CardView there's 2 TextViews, a title and a subtitle. The goal is when the user clicks on a specific CardView, I want to be able to change that CardView's subtitle text. My problem is that when I try to use the following code, it doesn't do that.

```
TextView subTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
subTitle.setText("Blah Blah Blah");
```

When I click on the first CardView it changes perfectly fine. The problem is when I click on the second one: it changes the first with the 2nd one's text.

I heard about assigning each TextView a custom ID when the onBindViewHolder method is called so I can put

```
TextView subTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.*something*.subtitle1);
subTitle.setText("Blah Blah Blah");
```

Would this be the correct course of action, and, if so, how would I go about doing so?

Here's my code so far:

OptionsAdapter.java

```
package com.alexbeschler.reversepolishnotation;

import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class OptionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OptionsAdapter.OptionsViewHolder> {
    private List<Option> optionList;
    private onItemClicked mOnItemClickListener;

    public OptionsAdapter(List<Option> optionList) {
        this.optionList = optionList;
    }

    @Override
    public OptionsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.options_card_view, viewGroup, false);
        return new OptionsViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(OptionsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Option option = optionList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(option.title);
        holder.subTitle.setText(option.subTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return optionList.size();
    }

    class OptionsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView title, subTitle;

        public OptionsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            subTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.subTitle);
            subTitle.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
            itemView.setClickable(true);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnItemClickListener != null) {
                mOnItemClickListener.onItemClick(v, getAdapterPosition());
            }
        }
    }

    public interface onItemClicked {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(onItemClicked mOnItemClickListener) {
        this.mOnItemClickListener = mOnItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

OptionsActivity.java

```
package com.alexbeschler.reversepolishnotation;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final String OPTIONS_FILE_NAME = "reversepolishnotation_options";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_options);

        //Instantiate the toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //Instantiate the RecyclerView
        RecyclerView optionsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        optionsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        optionsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        final OptionsAdapter optionsAdapter = new OptionsAdapter(createOptionsList());
        optionsList.setAdapter(optionsAdapter);
        optionsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OptionsAdapter.onItemClicked() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                optionsListener(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private List<Option> createOptionsList() {
        List<Option> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Option option1 = new Option(); 
        Option option2 = new Option();

        option1.title = "Integer Type";
        option1.subTitle = "Specifies what type of integer to use - " +
                readString("KEY_INTEGER_TYPE", "Double");
        list.add(option1);

        option2.title = "Rounding Mode";
        option2.subTitle = "Specifies how to round; only available in BigDecimal - " +
                readString("KEY_ROUNDING_MODE", "Half Up");
        list.add(option2);

        return list;
    }

    private void optionsListener(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                //Set the first CardView's subTitle text to something different
                break;
            case 1:
                //Set the second CardView's subTitle text to something different
                break;
            default:
        }
    }

    private String readString(String optionName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(OPTIONS_FILE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(optionName, defaultValue);
    }

    private void writeString(String optionName, String optionValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences(OPTIONS_FILE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(optionName, optionValue);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

activity_options.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.alexbeschler.reversepolishnotation.OptionsActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/cardList"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

options_card_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/padding15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/padding15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/padding15dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="17sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Usually when you change an item's view in recycler view, you should call the adapter's notifyItemChanged(position) method, which will call the onBindViewHolder with the changed position to update the view